# How to debug that why cron not working

Tags: php, cpanel

I have two cron job schedule in daily once basis at cpanel:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/publicwe/public_html/sts/class/payment/growth.php

/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/publicwe/public_html/sts/inc/payment/count_member.php
```

but the above cron is not working, and second cron is working. both files work well when directly runs on web browser. how to debug that why the first cron is not working ?

Comment: `1.` Review cron Log. `2.` See if include paths are relative and generate an error when run from Cron.

Comment: WHere to check cron log in cpanel ?

Answer (score 1):

You should check file's permissions are executable and also check logs for the same as:

> tail -f /var/log/cron

or

> grep filename /var/log/cron